# Does groovy-wslite support MTOM/attachments?

Tags: java, soap, groovy, attachment

Is it possible/reasonably easy to send attachments as a part of SOAP requests using groovy-wslite?

https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in support for attachments or MTOM, but it is possible since groovy-wslite provides almost complete control of the HTTP headers and payload that is sent.  However, it's definitely not reasonably easy since the burden of crafting the headers/payload would all be placed on the developer.

The goal of the groovy-wslite library is focused on relatively simple payloads and making it easy to craft XML payloads using either a String or MarkupBuilder.  For more advanced needs it probably best to look to more mature and robust libraries like JAX-WS, Apache CXF or Axis2.

Comment: John, your library is so simple to use in groovy for both soap and rest. Thank you so much and there are good examples which helps to use it which is more beautiful and helps users to use the library. Attachments example would be appreciated if possible.